# Laravel Expected response code 250 but got code “”, with message “” [hotmail]

Tags: php, laravel, email, windows-server-2008, hotmail

**I have an laravel app that send mails, the mailer run in localhost but in the server i have something like that:**

> Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message "" in C:\xampp\htdocs\bancalafortaleza\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php:383 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\bancalafortaleza\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(281): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_assertResponseCode('', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\bancalafortaleza\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\EsmtpTransport.php(270): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->executeCommand('RSET\r\n', Array, Array)

*The server is Windows Server and i cannot configure smtp or another things in this server*
please help me, you can see the question also [here](http://www.comunidadq.com/foro/ver/580ed8fcc2543f49a710cac1/error-laravel-swift-transportexception-expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-with-message)